# How to get html source after javascript made changes to the html (without a browser)

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I want to get the HTML source of a webpage.  I am aware I could get it using HttpRequest class (.NET Framework), but unfortunately, the HTML is not yet "fully formed" since the HTML I want would require clicking on a link/button at the webpage, which would then manipulate the HTML (and that's when I want to get the HTML source).

I've tried using the `WebBrowser` class/control (.NET Framework).  Even though this might allow me to get the manipulated HTML source, the webpage I'm trying to request will have pop-ups, and I can't have pop-ups.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Selenium, or maybe Headless Chrome could help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to click buttons, handle pop-ups, send post request etc.. 
you should take a look at  [Selenium](https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-c-sharp/). It gives you power to fully automates browsers and get any html on the page. 
You can await for some tag id exist and then get you html by instance.
Selinum can run browsers without UI, adding the parameter "--headless" on the webdriver.

Comment: This may just be what I'm looking for.  Thanks.